# Add more than one nested dynamic form by select dropdown in main dynamic form

Tags: jquery, yii2, nested-forms, dynamicform

I used dynamic form in yii2 like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwCuppvwgy4yay1wSEtUa1VFNUE/view?usp=sharing).
I want to add one other element to nested form when I select `twice_a_day` and add two other elements to nested form when I select `3_times_a_day` and so on.

Is there any solution?
How Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I extended DynamicFormWidget and changed javascripts that used for add items